# interpolating consecutive numbers

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Based on below Pandas DataFrame, there are time(second) & heartrate values.
Although 'time' should be consecutive numbers, we see some missing values. (1,2,4,5,7,9,10 etc) In that case, should I use pandas.DataFrame.interpolate to get desired result? or any other great idea to achieve it? Please note the original data are coming from API. I tried to look for any answers on the web, but no luck...

Original:

```
    time heartrate
    0   97
    3   105
    6   105
    8   111
    11  111
    13  114
    16  115
```

Desired output:

```
time    heartrate
0   97
1   100
2   103
3   105
4   105
5   105
6   105
7   109
8   111
9   111
10  111
11  111
12  113
13  114
14  114
15  114
16  115
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `time` as index then reindex with `pd.RangeIndex` to get continuous values and interpolate `heartrate`:

```
idx = pd.RangeIndex(df.time.min(), df.time.max()+1, name='time')

out = df.set_index('time').reindex(idx)['heartrate'] \
        .interpolate(method='linear') \
        .pipe(np.ceil) \
        .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    time  heartrate
0      0       97.0
1      1      100.0
2      2      103.0
3      3      105.0
4      4      105.0
5      5      105.0
6      6      105.0
7      7      108.0
8      8      111.0
9      9      111.0
10    10      111.0
11    11      111.0
12    12      113.0
13    13      114.0
14    14      115.0
15    15      115.0
16    16      115.0
```

**The result is imprecise**. You have to adjust the [interpolate method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) to get the desired result but the principle is the same.

Comment: Probably because the result is not exactly what is expected.

Comment: Thanks for your edit @jezrael. It's more constructive.

Comment: @Corralien - Not tested, but should working well

Answer (score 0):

You can `reindex` and `interpolate`, and use `np.ceil` to ceil the numbers:

```
(np.ceil(df.set_index('time')
           .reindex(range(df['time'].max()+1))
           .interpolate())
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
    time  heartrate
0      0       97.0
1      1      100.0
2      2      103.0
3      3      105.0
4      4      105.0
5      5      105.0
6      6      105.0
7      7      108.0
8      8      111.0
9      9      111.0
10    10      111.0
11    11      111.0
12    12      113.0
13    13      114.0
14    14      115.0
15    15      115.0
16    16      115.0
```

Comment: What is the difference between our methods??? Edit: I did not downvote!

Comment: np.ceil, not sure if reason for new answer.

Comment: @Corralien I just see your method, I had prepared my response ~30 min ago but could only press send now ;) However, I see yours is not vectorial, you should avoid the apply ;)

Comment: @mozway - Is possible us `pipe` for avoid `apply`

Comment: @jezrael yes, but as this is a Series, this works both ways.

Comment: Your solution does not work if the start time is 3 for instance.

Comment: As this is biological sampling I imagine the data is relative and the origin is always 0, if not one can `fillna`.

Comment: Removed DV again.